# Beginner having Problems with Restarting Scenes when Dying in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

so I’m trying to create a respawn system as a beginner, and everything seems to be working the first time but the second time it seems to be unbehaving. If anyone knows how to help me, I would appreciate it

LevelControl:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int index;
    public string levelName;
    public GameObject GameOverPanel;
    public static LevelControl instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            instance = GetComponent<LevelControl>();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            //Loading level with build index
            SceneManager.LoadScene(index);

            //Loading level with scene name
            SceneManager.LoadScene(levelName);

            //Restart level
            //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }
    public void LoadLevel1()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
    public GameObject GetGameOverScreen()
    {
        return GameOverPanel;
    }
}
```

PlayerMovement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController2D controller;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Move our character
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = false;
        //FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            //Destroy(FindObjectOfType<CharacterController2D>().gameObject);
            GameObject.Find("Player").SetActive(false);
            LevelControl.instance.GetGameOverScreen().SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Error In Unity Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFBKE.jpg

If your wondering what I'm trying to do, well, when the 2 colliders of the Player and Enemy collide, I want a restart button to pop up, and the Character to get destroyed, and after that restart the level as is.

Comment: Please post your code to a website where the certificates aren't invalid, or **even better** post a minimal, reproducible example here directly.

Comment: Hi! Please consider providing your code in the question.

Comment: So what exactly is your button calling? Also there is something `DontDestroyOnLoad` .. you are probably loosing reference due to destroying one of the duplicate instances? Actually you don't even use the `instance` at all .. do you need this `DontDesrroyOnLoad` then?

Comment: Is `GetGameOverScreenn` a child of the `LevelControl` object?

Comment: If you get an error in the console please post it here as text as well

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide much but I try to work with what we have.

In `LevelController` you have

```
private void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        instance = GetComponent<LevelControl>();
    }
}
```

First of all just use

```
instance = this;
```

;)

---

Then you are doing

```
LevelControl.instance.GetGameOverScreenn().SetActive(true);
```

I don't see your setup but probably `GetGameOverScreenn` might not exist anymore after the Scene reload while the `instance` still does due to the `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Actually, why even use a Singleton here? If you reload the entire scene anyway you could just setup the references once via the Inspector and wouldn't have to worry about them later after scene changes...

---

Also

```
GameObject.Find("Player").SetActive(false);
```

seems odd .. isn't your `PlayerController` attached to the Player object anyway? You could just use

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Normally it would be easier just to do this:

```
 if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        //Destroy(FindObjectOfType<CharacterController2D>().gameObject);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        LevelControl.instance.GetGameOverScreen().SetActive(true);
```

But this will NOT work if you want to attach the script to any other gameobjects for any reason. If you are then first make a game object variable containing the player, like this:

```
public GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
```

Then say

```
Player.SetActive(false);
```

This creates a player gameobject which you can access by calling the variable.